# How can I use gganimate with geom_tile?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate, geom-tile

I was having trouble animating a `geom_tile()` plot where the tile remains visible after it appears.

Here's my code using the `airquality` data.

First, the static plot. Here, the x-axis is Day. The y-axis is Month and Temp is the fill.

```
library(gganimate) 

anim <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Day, y = Month, fill = Temp)) +
  geom_tile()

anim
```

Static Tile Plot
[image]

Using `transition_reveal()` doesn't visually preserve the Temp tiles as it traverses along Day.

```
anim1 <- anim + transition_reveal(Day)
anim1
```

[image: Animated Tile Plot]

I also tried this with `transition_time()` with no luck.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility here is `transiton_manual`:

```
anim1 <- anim + transition_manual(Day, cumulative = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution Jon!

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with `transition_time()` and `shadow_mark()`

```
library(gganimate) 

anim <- ggplot(airquality, aes(x = Day, y = Month, fill = Temp)) +
  geom_tile()+ 
  transition_time(Day) +
  shadow_mark()
anim
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, TarJae!

Comment: You are welcome. Please if the answer was helpful then vote up and accept as answer (left top to the answer). Thanks.

Comment: Similarly, if you find the OP post good, then you could upvote their post as well. That's not only kind, but also you will not receive reps unless their reputation has a certain level.

Comment: @tjebo. Thank you for this valuable tip. I hadn't considered that yet.